# Visualize DGLGraph based model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working on a graph convolutional model taking `DGLGraph` as input. Is there any method to visualize the model structure?

I found libraries such as `torchsummary` and `visualdl` requires the input to be `pytorch tensors` or `python` data types.

Answer (score -1):

You could use multiple solution:

1.netron(Visualizer for neural network, deep learning and machine learning models):

[netron](http://%20%20%20%20https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)

2.ANNvisualizer:
[Visualizing Artificial Neural Networks (ANNs) with just One Line of Code](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-artificial-neural-networks-anns-with-just-one-line-of-code-b4233607209e)

3.NN-SVG:
[NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html)

4.dotnets
[dotnets](https://github.com/martisak/dotnets)
[enter link description here](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/draw-neural-network-diagrams-graphviz/)

and for more information please refer to this post [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-do-you-visualize-neural-network-architectures)

Comment: None of the above-mentioned frameworks supports DGLGraph.